# XML-INTO issue with RPGLE data structure

Tags: rpgle

Working on a program to read XML to RPG for the first time.  I'm not getting the data into my DS and when I try to view the subfields I get Identifier does not exist.

This is part of the sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<PRINTING> 
<HDR CW_DEPT_CD="736" CW_FILE_ID="W105B22355001" 
 CW_UNIT_CD="D736" BANK_ACCT_CD="GA" PYMT_DT="12/12/2022" 
 PROC_DT="12/12/2022" CHK_FRMT="GENZ" CHK_FRMT_DSCR="Generic Z-Fold" 
 DISB_CAT="SAM" DISB_CAT_DSCR="Sealed Agency Mailed" 
 DISB_HDLG_CD="null" DISB_HDLG_DSCR="null" STD_TXT="null" 
 BANK_ACCN_NO="936836402" BANK_NO="083000137" 
 DEPT_NM="Department For Community Based Services" 
 UNIT_NM="Department for Community Based Services" PERMIT_NO="null" 
 CNTAC_CD="76" EXTR_AD_1="ATTN: DAFM/TWIST" 
 EXTR_AD_2="275 East Main Street 3W-C" EXTR_AD_3="null" 
 EXTR_CITY="Frankfort" EXTR_ST="KY" ST_NM="null" EXTR_ZIP="40621" 
 EXTR_CTRY="null" EXTR_EMAIL_AD="null" PH_NO="502-564-3427" 
 PH_EXT="null" FAX_NO="null" />
```

And here is the program piece.

```
  dcl-ds HDR DIM(10) Qualified;
     CW_DEPT_CD char(4);         
     CW_FILE_ID  char(20);       
     CW_UNIT_CD  char(4);        
     BANK_ACCT_CD  char(4); ...more fields 

     dcl-ds PYMT_LINE;       
        LN_NO      char(6);    
        VEN_CUST_CD   char(20);
        LGL_NM    char(60);  ... more fields
     end-ds PYMT_LINE;                     
                                        
  end-ds HDR;      
  Eval options = 'path=PRINTING/HDR/PYMT_LINE +                     
                  case=any +                                
                  allowextra=yes +                          
                  allowmissing=yes +                        
                  doc=file +                                
                  datasubf=value';                          
                                                             
  xml-into HDR                                                     
           %XML(Filename:options);
```

I appreciate any feedback.

Thanks

Tried everything that I could find.

Comment: That's not enough of the XML doc to know what's wrong

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem is...
If your program compiles, runs, and doesn't crash, then there are no syntax errors.
How are you trying to view the field values? Here you need to take into account that if your structure is declared as qualified, then all nested structures are also automatically qualified and you need to access the fields not HDR.LN_NO, but HDR.PYMT_LINE.LN_NO
https://www.rpgpgm.com/2017/04/nested-data-structures-in-rpg.html

Comment: The original post didn't have line breaks in the XML so only the first line showed up.

Answer (score 1):

You have path=PRINTING/HDR/PYMT_LINE, but your data structure matches HDR.

The path should point to the element that matches your data structure, so I think it should just be path=PRINTING/HDR.

Using allowextra=yes and allowmissing=yes is ok when you have your XML-INTO working with that XML, but it can make it difficult to develop a new XML-INTO. With those options, the data structure can completely mismatch the XML document.

So when I'm development a new XML-INTO, I don't code those options. Instead, I make a temporary version of the XML that matches the data structure exactly. Then when I have it working, I might add allowextra=yes if I think the XML might have extra elements.

But I almost never add allowmissing=yes. Instead, I use the countprefix option. Here's a useful article that discusses allowmissing vs countprefix (among other things :-)

Comment: The xml file does have PRINTING/HDR/PYMT_LINE                                                           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<PRINTING> 
<HDR CW_DEPT_CD="736"/>
   <PYMT_LINE LN_NO="1" VEND_CUST_CD="ZZMISCINDV"  />
</PRINTING>

Comment: Barbara, Could the way the xml is formed have anything to do with it?

Comment: The XML file has PRINTING/HDR/PYMT_LINE, but your HDR data structure matches the PRINTING/HDR path. Did you try with path=PRINTING/HDR?

Does the XML have multiple instances of HDR? Or is there one HDR with multiple instances of PYMT_LINE? If so, then you want the DIM keyword on PYMT_LINE, not on HDR. And then you could do XML-INTO HDR.PYMT_LINE with path=PRINTING/HDR/PYMT_LINE.

Comment: Barbara,That is correct there is only one HDR and multiple PYMT_LINE.  So made those changes, program compiles fine, but when I debug and display DS variable nothing is loaded. I have the ds as dcl-ds HDR Qualified;  with the dcl-ds PYMT_LINE  DIM(1000); the path PRINTING/HDR/PYMT_LINE and xml-into HDR.PYMT_LINE.

Comment: Try removing allowmissing=yes and allowextra=yes from your options. The XML-INTO will probably fail with an exception and the error message might help you find out what's wrong with your data structure

Comment: It might also be a good idea to create a temporary simplified version of the XML where it only has two PYMT_LINE elements, and each PYMT_LINE element only has one child element.

Then create a simplified data structure to match that simplified XML, and for sure you should remove the allowmissing and allowextra options for that simplified test.

Comment: I had already removed the allow options and the test xml only has 8 PYMT_LINE elements so it's not huge. This is what I get when I eval the the DS. EVAL HDR                  
HDR.CW_DEPT_CD = '    '   
HDR.CW_FILE_ID = '        
HDR.CW_UNIT_CD = '    '   
HDR.BANK_ACCT_CD = '    ' 
HDR.PYMT_DT = '          '
HDR.PROC_DT = '          '
HDR.CHK_FRMT = '    '     
HDR.CHK_FRMT_DSCR =       
         '                
HDR.DISB_CAT = '    '     
HDR.DISB_CAT_DSCR = '  '  
HDR.DISB_HDLG_CD = '    ' 
HDR.DISB_HDLG_DSCR = '  '   Does XML-INTO require each element endtags

Comment: I've validated the xml and it comes back valid, but each element doesn't have endtags.

Comment: If the XML start tag ends with /> then it shouldn't have an endtag. The HDR tag in your OP ends with /> so it doesn't need an endtag.

Comment: But there should be an endtag for PRINTING because the start tag just ends with >

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with a reduced form of your XML and your data structure and get that working. And then gradually add back the XML data and the subfields to match.

For example, start with this XML (I have this in a file xmltest.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>        
<PRINTING>                                         
<HDR CW_DEPT_CD="736" CW_FILE_ID="W105B22355001" />
</PRINTING>
```

And this RPG program:

```
dcl-ds HDR Qualified;                      
   CW_DEPT_CD char(4);                     
   CW_FILE_ID  char(20);                   
end-ds;                                    
dcl-s options varchar(100);                
                                           
Eval options = 'path=PRINTING/HDR +        
                case=any +                 
                doc=file +                 
                datasubf=value';           
                                           
xml-into hdr %xml('xmltest.xml' : options);
return;
```

Comment: I'm now getting the HDR elements loaded, which is progress.  When I add the PYMT_LINE DS back to the program it fails to load again.  Reason code 1. I had a couple typos in field names but corrected them and it still fails to loads. I reduced the number of elements in the pymt DS to 2. Still fails.

Comment: In your original XML, there is no PYMT_LINE, and the HDR element ends with the final "/>". Is PYMT_LINE a child of HDR, or is it a child of PRINTING?

Comment: <PRINTING> 
<HDR CW_DEPT_CD="736" CW_FILE_ID="W105B22355001" CW_UNIT_CD="D736" />
   <PYMT_LINE LN_NO="1" VEND_CUST_CD="ZZMISCINDV" />
   <PYMT_LINE LN_NO="2" VEND_CUST_CD="ZZMISCINDV" />
   <PYMT_LINE LN_NO="3" VEND_CUST_CD="ZZMISCINDV" />
   <PYMT_LINE LN_NO="4" VEND_CUST_CD="ZZMISCINDV" />
   <PYMT_LINE LN_NO="5" VEND_CUST_CD="ZZMISCINDV" />
   <PYMT_LINE LN_NO="6" VEND_CUST_CD="ZZMISCINDV" />
   <PYMT_LINE LN_NO="7" VEND_CUST_CD="ZZMISCINDV" />
   <PYMT_LINE LN_NO="8" VEND_CUST_CD="ZZMISCINDV" />
</PRINTING>

Comment: Yes it is a child of HDR

Comment: It's not a child of HDR. The PYMT_LINE elements are children of PRINTING. The /> at the end of the HDR tag ends the HDR tag. If the PYMT_LINE elements were children of HDR, there would be a </HDR> endtag after the PYMT_LINE elements.

Your RPG data structure has to have the top level name PRINTING, with two subfields HDR and PYMT_LINE. Do your XML-INTO with the PRINTING data structure, and specify path=PRINTING (or leave out the path option).

Comment: I see what you mean, I made those changes and was able to get everything loaded. I added DS(template) for the elements in HDR and PYMT_Line.   Now I'm wondering that with a live xml file that could have thousands of PYMT_LINE's if this will work.  I'm trying too load the data into a file. Could I hit any limitations?

Comment: That's what %HANDLER is for. You could get the HDR info first with a simple XML-INTO and then do a second XML-INTO with %HANDLER to get the PYMT_LINE info more gradually. There's an example using %HANDLER here: https://www.scottklement.com/presentations/Web%20Services%20and%20XML%20for%20RPGers.pdf

Comment: So I've created the PR xml-into %Handler( LoadData : pycnt ) %xml(file: options);  but compile is failing.  The first parameter of the procedure specified for %HANDLER
must exist and be passed by reference.    I have pycnt defined dcl-s pycnt   Int(10)

Comment: I'm getting the first xml-into working with the HDR DS but the xml-into with the handler is not loading.  I know it going thru handler because it is writing out to my db file.

Comment: dcl-ds HDR LikeDS(HDR_T) ; 
dcl-ds PYMT_LINE LikeDS(PYMT_T) DIM(400);   
Eval opts = 'path=PRINTING/PYMT_LINE +
case=any allowextra=yes  allowmissing=yes doc=file datasubf=value';          
xml-into %Handler( LoadData : pycnt ) %xml('/home/Treas/EMARS/XML/xmltest2.xml': opts)
dcl-proc LoadData  ;                  
Dcl-Pi  *N  Int(10);                                        
   pycnt  Int(10);                                          
   postData  LikeDS(PYMT_LINE)  dim(%elem(PYMT_LINE)) Const;
      items  int(10)  Value;                                   
End-Pi;

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say the handler is not loading but you know it is going through the handler. What does "not loading" mean?

Comment: I have the xml-into for HDR ds outside of the %handler.  HDR is getting loaded with data.  The xml-into with the %handler to load PYMT_LINE is not loading data, but I know it is going through the handler because the write to my DB file is within the handler and I'm getting records written to it. The DB file is made up of the HDR data and PYMT_LINE data, so I'm getting half the data written for each record.

Comment: Do you mean that the handler is getting called but it the parameter does not have the data from the XML file? I see you have allowextra=yes allowmissing=yes in your options. Try taking those out (temporarily make your XML match the data structure exactly). My guess is that you have the path wrong so it is not finding any subfield matches.